# An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

Tags: mysql, symfony, visual-studio-code, pdo, mamp

I'm on Mac, I've download Visual Studio Code and Mamp. I installed Symfony. I didn't install anything else, it seems to me that I have to install MySql ? I thought I didn't need it as I've been using MySql through Mamp, but in the other post I understood that I should?

Now, on Symfony, I've tried to create a database with

```
doctrine:database:create
```

I received an error

```
An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
```

Following the other post, I've checked on `phpinfo()` and I do have PDO mysql enable. But it doesn't appear anywhere in my php.ini (when I go to Mamp->bin->php->php7.4.9->conf->php.ini). I've read that I should see `extension=php_mysqli.so` and `php_pdo_pgsql.so` and `php_pdo_mysql.so`

Do I need to add it myself?

Update : Result for php bin/console debug:config doctrine :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                host: localhost
                port: null
                user: root
                password: null
                logging: true
                profiling: true
                profiling_collect_backtrace: false
                profiling_collect_schema_errors: true
                options: {  }
                mapping_types: {  }
                slaves: {  }
                replicas: {  }
                shards: {  }
        types: {  }
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '/Users/mathildedion/chamla 15.53.49/src/Entity'
                        prefix: App\Entity
                        alias: App
                        mapping: true
                query_cache_driver:
                    type: null
                metadata_cache_driver:
                    type: null
                result_cache_driver:
                    type: null
                class_metadata_factory_name: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory
                default_repository_class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
                quote_strategy: doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.default
                entity_listener_resolver: null
                repository_factory: doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory
                hydrators: {  }
                filters: {  }
        proxy_dir: '%kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
        proxy_namespace: Proxies
        resolve_target_entities: {  }
```

Comment: What do you see for driver when you run `php bin/console debug:config doctrine` ?

Comment: @ArleighHix I just added the result for php bin/console debug:config doctrine in my post ! It wasn't clear when posted in comment.

Comment: Could you check "conf.d/" folder to check extensions. I "pdo_mysql" is not present you have to install the driver for php

Comment: @qdequippe I can't find any conf.d folder ... I downloaded PHP on my Mac and modified the php.ini (in which I could fine pdo_mysql, so I just took off the " ; "). Now it says that :  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Ok cool! so you have to create a database now

Comment: @qdequippe yes, and it is not working :(( I have the error 1045 saying Access denied for user "root"@"localhost"... I've checked on Mamp and my password is root

Comment: @MathildeD it's another subject but try to read Mamp docs and try to access your database for example using MySQL Workbench ...

Comment: @qdequippe sorted ! I downloaded PHP and MySql on my Mac, changed the password on MySql, updated the .env and it's not working, the database has been created. I still have the warning : PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_mysql (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_mysql, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/pdo_mysql.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0